# Looking for Python Equivalent of R's rpart function

Tags: python, r

I am working on a project that uses a software with Python and R integration.  the R integration for the software is not as well documented as I would like and many users of the software may not be familiar with R.  Because of this, I would like to convert my script (made using the rpart function in R) to Python. The main two outputs of this function that I need are the predicted values outputs and the decision tree visualization.

What I would like to know is whether there is a Python equivalent to the rpart function (e.g., if I input the same data into rpart and the Python equivalent will I get the same results?)  if there isn't a perfect equivalent i am also ok with using an alternative function so long as there is some documentation explaining how the two are different.

If it is relevant to your answer, the software is ArcMap, however I would also like to develop a script for QGIS in the near future.

---

edit:
Link to rpart documentation:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf

---

Comment: better add link to `rpart` documentation.

Comment: just added it!~